# how to make grep use a "from X to Y" syntax? (Using date as parameter)

Tags: perl, grep

so I would like to write a script that scans through orders and files and pastes certain lines of these files into a file.

How can I let my file scan through a specified range instead of a singular date?

Actually the code I'd need to change looks like this:

```
$curdir = "$scriptdir\\$folder";
opendir my $dir_b,  "$curdir" or die "Can't open directory: $!";
my @file = grep { /$timestamp/ } readdir $dir_b;
closedir $dir_b;
```

Now line 3 needs to work actually like this

```
my @file = grep { /$timestamp1 to $timestamp2/ } readdir $dir_b;
```

anyone knows how to achieve this? timestamp1 would be as example 20160820 and timestamp2 would be 20160903 or 20160830

thanks for the help

Comment: So you want to grep for all numbers between timestamp1 and timestamp2?

Comment: `my @file = grep { /$timestamp1/ .. /$timestamp2/ } readdir $dir_b;`

Comment: @Сухой27 That's the flip-flop, right? Wouldn't that match everything between the occurrences of `$timestamp1` and `$timestamp2`?

Comment: @simbabque  It matches 20160820, 20160821, ...  -- this is required, no? Or what do you mean by "_everything_"?

Comment: @zdim yeah it does. It's smart and elegant.

Comment: @simbabque  yes, I really like the [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) -- allows very naturally looking things to be done.

Comment: this also worked, thanks

Comment: @simbabque yes, everything between and including boundaries.

Comment: @Сухой27 I posted your comment-answer as a Wiki, thinking that it would be a shame to not show more prominently while fearing that you won't post it as an answer. If you don't approve of that please let me know how to remedy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Regexp::Assemble](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) to build one pattern out of all timestamps that are in the range of your dates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Assemble;

my $timestamp_late  = 20160830;
my $timestamp_early = 20160820;

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
$ra->add( $_ ) for $timestamp_early .. $timestamp_late;

print $ra->re;
```

The pattern for that case is: `(?^:201608(?:2\d|30))`

You can now use it like this:

```
my $pattern = $ra->re;
my @files = grep { /$pattern/ } readdir $dir_b;
```

It works by combining multiple patterns into a single one.

> Regexp::Assemble takes an arbitrary number of regular expressions and assembles them into a single regular expression (or RE) that matches all that the individual REs match.
>
> As a result, instead of having a large list of expressions to loop over, a target string only needs to be tested against one expression. This is interesting when you have several thousand patterns to deal with. Serious effort is made to produce the smallest pattern possible.

Our patterns here are rather simple (they are just strings), but it works nonetheless. The resulting pattern works like this:

```
(?^:                ) # non-capture group w/o non-default flags for the sub pattern
    201608            # literal 201608
          (?:      )  # non-capture group
             2\d      # literal 2 followed by a digit (0-9)
                |     # or
                 30   # literal 30
```

The `(?^:)` is explained [in this part of perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3F%5Ealuimnsx%3Apattern)).

If you pass in more numbers, the resulting regex will look different. Of course this is not meant for dates, so with my simple `1 .. 9` expression we get all numbers in between. The `..` is the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), and will return the list `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` for the aforementioned case.

So if you wanted to make sure that you only get valid dates, you could take [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4375789/1331451) or [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622999/1331451). Here's an example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Assemble;
use DateTime;

my $timestamp_late  = DateTime->new( year => 2016, month => 9, day => 1 );
my $timestamp_early = DateTime->new( year => 2016, month => 8, day => 19 );    # -1 day

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
while ( $timestamp_early->add( days => 1 ) <= $timestamp_late ) {
    $ra->add( $timestamp_early->ymd(q{}) );
}

print $ra->re;
```

This goes over to the next month and gives

```
(?^:20160(?:8(?:3[01]|2\d)|901))
```

which, only matches real dates, while the other, simpler, solution will include all numbers between them, including the 99th of August.

```
(?^:20160(?:8(?:2\d|3\d|4\d|5\d|6\d|7\d|8\d|9\d)|90[01]))
```

Comment: this worked well, if someone is interested I'd appreciate a summary what it is actually doing, is it also including Dates like 20160855 that do not exist in its pattern? If yes I understand how it is working. thanks :)

Comment: @ZesaRex  If you give it the end of `20160903`, yes it will. As it stands, it goes from `20` to `30`. The range `$a .. $b` generates _all_ numbers inbetween. The invalid dates don't exist in your filenames so that should still work.  If it's a concern, you can feed it more carefully selected patterns.

Comment: @ZesaRex I added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Solution by [`Сухой27`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927), posted as a comment

```
my @file = grep { /$timestamp1/ .. /$timestamp2/ } readdir $dir_b;
```

A very nice example of use of the [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

Answer (score 2):

I favor some simpler approaches that are easy for someone to understand. The flip-flop is cool, but almost no one knows what it does.

You don't have to do everything in one operation:

```
 my @file = grep { 
    my $this_date = ...;
    $lower_date <= $this_date and $this_date <= $higher_date; 
    } @inputs;
```

Comment: Absolutely agree, I had something very similar almost typed in when the range-based comment showed up.  But I do think that people "should" learn about the `range` operator since it adds to the language a way to write very clean code, which also fits in nicely with other tools. This, in my opinion, plays very well with Perl's fluid semantics.

Comment: I also thought about this approach, but decided against it because you also need to break apart every line of the file to get the dates out. The regex solution felt cleaner somehow.